# Is it possible to replace JOIN with UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT (CASE
         WHEN [ A ] . [ Gender ] IS NULL THEN
          [ B ] . [ Gender ]
         ELSE
          [ A ] . [ Gender ]
       END) AS [ Gender ],
       (CASE
         WHEN [ A ] . [ StatVal ] IS NULL THEN
          [ B ] . [ StatVal ]
         ELSE
          [ A ] . [ StatVal ]
       END) AS [ StatVal ],
       (CASE
         WHEN [ A ] . [ COUNT ] IS NULL THEN
          0
         ELSE
          [ A ] . [ COUNT ]
       END) AS [ COUNT ]
  FROM (SELECT [ Gender ], [ StatVal ], COUNT(*) AS [ COUNT ]
          FROM [ TestTable ]
         GROUP BY [ Gender ], [ StatVal ]) AS [ A ]
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT [ G ] . [ Gender ], [ T ] . [ StatVal ]
                     FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [ Gender ] FROM [ TestTable ]) AS [ G ],
                          (SELECT DISTINCT [ StatVal ] FROM [ TestTable ]) AS [ T ]) AS [ B ]
    ON [ A ] . [ Gender ] = [ B ] . [ Gender ]
   AND [ A ] . [ StatVal ] = [ B ] . [ StatVal ]
 WHERE [ B ] . [ StatVal ] <> ''
   AND [ B ] . [ Gender ]  <> ''
```

The above query gives the output

| Gender | StatVal | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Male | 01 | 1 |
| Male | 02 | 0 |
| Female | 01 | 0 |
| Female | 02 | 1 |
| Trans | 01 | 0 |
| Trans | 02 | 0 |

Is it possible to replace the above RIGHT OUTER JOIN with UNION

The TestTable Structure

| Gender | StatVal | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Male | 01 | A |
| Female |  | B |
| Female |  | C |
| Female | 02 | D |
| Male |  | E |
| Trans |  | F |

The expected output is, all possible combinations of Gender and Statval  with counts

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you would do better when providing some sample input and expected outcome. Also the query you already use(?), looks far too complicated. Do you know how COALESCE works? This could make it much simpler.

Comment: Wow this is so hard to read with all the extra spaces. Use coalesce instead of all these case expressions. Also, using a right join is an odd decision here. Most people don't think like that. It would be simpler to to switch this around and use a left join. But looking at this I don't think you need any joins at all and no subqueries. This could almost certainly be done with a single select statement.

Comment: @JonasMetzler, Thanks for your response. I have updated the TestTable structure. The expected output is, all possible combinations of Gender and Statval with counts

Comment: @SeanLange Ya I tried coalesce  instead of all these case statements. But I am not sure how to replace RIGHT OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a much simpler version of the same query and only accesses the table once:

```
SELECT Gender, StatVal, COUNT(*)
  FROM dbo.TestTable
  WHERE Gender <> '' AND StatVal <> ''
  GROUP BY Gender, StatVal;
```

If there is something missing here (e.g. you want rows for all 6 combinations even if the combination doesn't exist), your requirements should state that. But you can do that with a control CTE, e.g.:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT Gender, StatVal FROM 
  (VALUES('Male'),('Female'),('Trans')) AS g(Gender)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES('01'),('02')) AS s(StatVal)
)
SELECT cte.Gender, cte.StatVal, 
    [COUNT] = SUM(CASE WHEN t.Gender IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  FROM cte
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TestTable AS t
  ON cte.Gender = t.Gender
  AND cte.StatVal = t.StatVal
  GROUP BY cte.Gender, cte.StatVal;
```

And if you need to *dynamically* determine all the possible genders and stat vals:

```
WITH g AS 
(
  SELECT Gender FROM dbo.TestTable WHERE Gender <> ''
  GROUP BY Gender
),
s AS
(
  SELECT StatVal FROM dbo.TestTable WHERE StatVal <> ''
  GROUP BY StatVal
)
SELECT g.Gender, s.StatVal, 
    [COUNT] = SUM(CASE WHEN t.Gender IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  FROM g CROSS JOIN s
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TestTable AS t
  ON g.Gender = t.Gender
  AND s.StatVal = t.StatVal
  GROUP BY g.Gender, s.StatVal;
```

Working examples [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cCQ_XP9m).

And [here's an example](https://dbfiddle.uk/hkLYDNEw) that uses derived tables instead of CTEs - for identical performance but ... *different* readability.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The expected output is, all possible combinations of Gender and Statval with counts.     

| Male     |  01   |  1    |
| Male     |  02   |  0    |
| Female |  01   |  0    |
| Female |  02   |  1    |
| Trans    |  01   |  0    |
| Trans    |  02   |  0    |

Comment: I was about to post a nearly identical answer to your last query. That seems to be what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Other than CTE, is there any way to achieve the same?

Comment: @jeenap What is wrong with a CTE? Would you rather use derived tables? They're the same thing (though arguably [less readable](https://dbfiddle.uk/hkLYDNEw)).